# How to make Protractor work while using Cloud9?

Tags: angularjs, cloud, protractor

I am new to Cloud9 and I am trying to use Protractor for e2e testing. I am running the angular-phonecat examples.

The error is the folowing:

```
Using ChromeDriver directly...
/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/atoms/error.js:109
  var template = new Error(this.message);
                 ^
UnknownError: chrome not reachable
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.10.267518,platform=Linux 3.14.13-c9 x86_64)
    at new bot.Error (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/atoms/error.js:109:18)
..
```

I installed the chromedriver. The only thing is how to install the actual Chrome on cloud9 and run the tests?

Thank you in advance,

cheers,
Haytham

Answer (score 11):

I'm a fan of webase IDE and [Cloud9](https://c9.io/) is one of the best.   Here a way to install Xvfb, chrome and [Protractor](https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/) for doing  [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/) end-to-end automated testing on Cloud9

**Open a terminal (xvfb already installed on c9.io)**

- install X11 fonts

  ```
  $ sudo apt-get install -y xfonts-100dpi xfonts-75dpi xfonts-scalable xfonts-cyrillic
  ```
- install last chrome

  ```
  $ wget -q -O - \
    https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub \
    | sudo apt-key add - 
  $ sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main"  \
    >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list'
  $ sudo apt-get update 
  $ sudo apt-get install -y google-chrome-stable
  ```
- install protractor

  ```
  $ npm install -g protractor
  ```
- update webdriver

  ```
  $ webdriver-manager update
  ```
- use --no-sandbox option with chrome

  As c9.io is running inside container this option is needed.
  Update protractor *conf.js* to pass the option to chrome

  ```
  capabilities: {
    browserName: 'chrome',
    'chromeOptions': {
      args: ['--no-sandbox'] 
    }   
  }
  ```

**run protractor test on headless chrome**

- start webdriver with xvfb (headless)

  ```
  $ xvfb-run webdriver-manager start
  ```
- run the test on other terminal

  ```
  $ protrator conf.js
  ```

From http://blog.maduma.com

Comment: Had to install xvfb on the current version of c9.io:
`sudo apt-get install -y xvfb`

Comment: If you run into a `Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-i386/Packages'` error, change `deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main` to `deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main`

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible to 'install' browsers onto cloud9 to run browser-based end-to-end test scenarios. The selenium web driver is looking to load chrome on which to run the tests but is throwing an error as it isn't something which can be found on the cloud9 development environment.

If you are committed to running these tests on an online IDE like cloud9 your only option is to use a headless browser like phantomJS but a note of caution from protractor docs

> We recommend against using PhantomJS for tests with Protractor. There are many reported issues with PhantomJS crashing and behaving differently from real browsers.

I would recommend downloading your app locally and running extensive E2E tests across the browsers which your users will actually be using to access your app.

Another option is to use something like Saucelabs (https://saucelabs.com/) for automated cloud-based cross-browser testing; this will need some configuration in the `protractor_conf.js` file. Note that there may be additional costs involved with cloud-based testing.

Answer (score 0):

I just tested this and it is working for me on my chromebook. It contains all of the steps necessary to complete the first page of https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial, including setting up the protractor tests.

```
create new blank workspace

run these commands
  rm -rf * .c9
  git clone --depth=16 https://github.com/angular/angular-phonecat.git
  cd angular-phonecat
  nvm install 7
  nvm alias default node
  npm install minimatch
  sudo npm install npm -g


edit this file
  angular-phonecat/package.json
    "start": "http-server ./app -a $IP -p $PORT -c-1"

run these commands
  npm start

click 'Share'
browse to url next to 'Application'

yay! the phonecat webapp should be running!



karma
  add these lines to karma.conf.js
    hostname: process.env.IP,
    port: process.env.PORT
  edit package.json
    "test": "karma start karma.conf.js --no-browsers"
  run this command
    npm test
  browse to http://<projectName>.<cloud9User>.c9.io:8081
  go forth and test!



protractor
  run these commands
    sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get install -y xvfb
    wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | sudo apt-key add -
    sudo sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list'
    sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get install -y google-chrome-stable
  edit protractor.conf.js
    capabilities: {
      'browserName': 'chrome',
      'chromeOptions': {
        args: ['--no-sandbox']
      }
    }
  run these commands
    npm install -g protractor
    sudo webdriver-manager update
    xvfb-run webdriver-manager start
  edit protractor.conf.js
    baseUrl: 'http://' + process.env.IP + ':' + process.env.PORT + '/'
    seleniumAddress: 'http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub'
  run these commands
    protractor protractor.conf.js
```