# How to run protractor remotely?

Tags: protractor, cloud9-ide

I am looking for a way to run/create protractor tests remotely because not able to run it locally on my machine. Anyone has any experience with running a commandline on a site like cloud 9 and protractor?

Answer (score 0):

Please check out [How to make Protractor work while using Cloud9?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27370707/how-to-make-protractor-work-while-using-cloud9) which provides some instructions on using Protractor with Cloud9.